# How to fix error where a KerasTensor is passed to a TF API?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, typeerror, tf.keras

I've downloaded code for a Wasserstein GAN with Gradient Policy (WGAN-GP) from [Keras-GAN (GitHub)](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN). Some of the imports appeared to be of outdated syntax, as I was getting errors and they were based on the pre-Tensorflow Keras. After a while of searching and tinkering, I have determined that I have no idea what to do next.

What I do know is that, in the following code, both the,

```
interpolated_img = RandomWeightedAverage()([real_img, fake_img])
```

and the,

```
validity_interpolated = self.critic(interpolated_img)
```

are both of the type KerasTensor or, more specifically, of type,

```
<class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>
```

and that immediately after printing both their types, the program crashes. So, it certainly seems to be caused by these objects.

Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate # _Merge
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from functools import partial

import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

from keras.layers.merge import _Merge

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sys

import numpy as np

class RandomWeightedAverage(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    """Provides a (random) weighted average between real and generated image samples"""
    def __init__(self, batch_size=32):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        alpha = tf.random.uniform((32, 1, 1, 1))
        return (alpha * inputs[0]) + ((1 - alpha) * inputs[1])

    def comput_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]


class WGANGP():
    def __init__(self, height=128, width=128, channels=3, noise_dim=100, batch_size=64):
        self.img_height = height
        self.img_width = width
        self.channels = channels
        self.img_shape = (self.img_height, self.img_width, self.channels)
        self.noise_dim = noise_dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        # Following parameter and optimizer set as recommended in paper
        self.n_critic = 5
        optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.00005)

        # Build the generator and critic
        self.generator = self.build_generator()
        self.critic = self.build_critic()

        #-------------------------------
        # Construct Computational Graph
        #       for the Critic
        #-------------------------------

        # Freeze generator's layers while training critic
        self.generator.trainable = False

        # Image input (real sample)
        real_img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

        # Noise input
        z_disc = Input(shape=(self.noise_dim,))
        # Generate image based of noise (fake sample)
        fake_img = self.generator(z_disc)

        # Discriminator determines validity of the real and fake images
        fake = self.critic(fake_img)
        valid = self.critic(real_img)

        # Construct weighted average between real and fake images
        interpolated_img = RandomWeightedAverage()([real_img, fake_img])
        # Determine validity of weighted sample
        validity_interpolated = self.critic(interpolated_img)

        # Use Python partial to provide loss function with additional
        # 'averaged_samples' argument
        partial_gp_loss = partial(self.gradient_penalty_loss,
                          averaged_samples=interpolated_img)
        partial_gp_loss.__name__ = 'gradient_penalty' # Keras requires function names

        self.critic_model = Model(inputs=[real_img, z_disc],
                            outputs=[valid, fake, validity_interpolated])
        self.critic_model.compile(loss=[self.wasserstein_loss,
                                              self.wasserstein_loss,
                                              partial_gp_loss],
                                        optimizer=optimizer,
                                        loss_weights=[1, 1, 10])
        #-------------------------------
        # Construct Computational Graph
        #         for Generator
        #-------------------------------

        # For the generator we freeze the critic's layers
        self.critic.trainable = False
        self.generator.trainable = True

        # Sampled noise for input to generator
        z_gen = Input(shape=(self.noise_dim,))
        # Generate images based of noise
        img = self.generator(z_gen)
        # Discriminator determines validity
        valid = self.critic(img)
        # Defines generator model
        self.generator_model = Model(z_gen, valid)
        self.generator_model.compile(loss=self.wasserstein_loss, optimizer=optimizer)

    def gradient_penalty_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, averaged_samples):
        """
        Computes gradient penalty based on prediction and weighted real / fake samples
        """
        gradients = K.gradients(y_pred, averaged_samples)[0]
        # compute the euclidean norm by squaring ...
        gradients_sqr = K.square(gradients)
        #   ... summing over the rows ...
        gradients_sqr_sum = K.sum(gradients_sqr,
                                  axis=np.arange(1, len(gradients_sqr.shape)))
        #   ... and sqrt
        gradient_l2_norm = K.sqrt(gradients_sqr_sum)
        # compute lambda * (1 - ||grad||)^2 still for each single sample
        gradient_penalty = K.square(1 - gradient_l2_norm)
        # return the mean as loss over all the batch samples
        return K.mean(gradient_penalty)


    def wasserstein_loss(self, y_true, y_pred):
        return K.mean(y_true * y_pred)

    def build_generator(self):

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Dense(128 * 7 * 7, activation="relu", input_dim=self.noise_dim))
        model.add(Reshape((7, 7, 128)))
        model.add(UpSampling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(UpSampling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(Conv2D(self.channels, kernel_size=4, padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("tanh"))

        model.summary()
        #
        # noise = Input(shape=(self.noise_dim,))
        # img = model(noise)

        return model  # Model(noise, img)

    def build_critic(self):

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=3, strides=2, input_shape=self.img_shape, padding="same"))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
        model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0,1),(0,1))))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same"))
        model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8))
        model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))
        model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(1))

        model.summary()

        # img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)
        # validity = model(img)

        return model  # Model(img, validity)

    def train(self, epochs, batch_size, sample_interval=50):

        # Load the dataset
        (X_train, _), (_, _) = mnist.load_data()

        # Rescale -1 to 1
        X_train = (X_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
        X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train, axis=3)

        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = -np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        fake = np.ones((batch_size, 1))
        dummy = np.zeros((batch_size, 1))  # Dummy gt for gradient penalty
        for epoch in range(epochs):

            for _ in range(self.n_critic):

                # ---------------------
                #  Train Discriminator
                # ---------------------

                # Select a random batch of images
                idx = np.random.randint(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size)
                imgs = X_train[idx]
                # Sample generator input
                noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, self.noise_dim))
                # Train the critic
                d_loss = self.critic_model.train_on_batch([imgs, noise],
                                                          [valid, fake, dummy])

            # ---------------------
            #  Train Generator
            # ---------------------

            g_loss = self.generator_model.train_on_batch(noise, valid)

            # Plot the progress
            print ("%d [D loss: %f] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], g_loss))

            # If at save interval => save generated image samples
            if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
                self.sample_images(epoch)

    def sample_images(self, epoch):
        r, c = 5, 5
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (r * c, self.noise_dim))
        gen_imgs = self.generator.predict(noise)

        # Rescale images 0 - 1
        gen_imgs = 0.5 * gen_imgs + 0.5

        fig, axs = plt.subplots(r, c)
        cnt = 0
        for i in range(r):
            for j in range(c):
                axs[i,j].imshow(gen_imgs[cnt, :,:,0], cmap='gray')
                axs[i,j].axis('off')
                cnt += 1
        fig.savefig("images/mnist_%d.png" % epoch)
        plt.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    img_width = 28
    img_height = 28
    channels = 1
    wgan = WGANGP(height=img_height, width=img_width, channels=channels)
    wgan.train(epochs=30000, batch_size=32, sample_interval=100)
```

I get the following error first:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[REDACTED PATH]", line 255, in <module>
    wgan.train(epochs=30000, batch_size=32, sample_interval=100)
  File "[REDACTED PATH]", line 215, in train
    d_loss = self.critic_model.train_on_batch([imgs, noise],
  File "J:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2093, in train_on_batch
    logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "J:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "J:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1147, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
```

Which is immediately followed by:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    File "J:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "[REDACTED PATH]", line 117, in gradient_penalty_loss  *
        gradients = K.gradients(y_pred, averaged_samples)[0]
    File "J:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 4352, in gradients  **
        return tf.compat.v1.gradients(
    File "J:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 102, in asarray
        return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    File "J:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\keras_tensor.py", line 254, in __array__
        raise TypeError(

    TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(32, 28, 28, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='random_weighted_average/add:0', description="created by layer 'random_weighted_average'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispa
tchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by
 putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem disabling eager execution

`from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import disable_eager_execution`

`disable_eager_execution()`

I also read some answers which suggested that this problem might be due to numpy 1.20>= , If the solution above doesn't work try downgrading numpy to like 1.19.5

Comment: I get this error: `ValueError: Your model contains layers that can only be successfully run in eager execution (layers constructed with dynamic=True). You must enable eager execution with tf.enable_eager_execution().` I have a quantum layer made with pennylane with `QuantumConv = qml.qnn.KerasLayer(circuit, params_shape, output_dim=n_qubits)`. Then I need to use `tf.concat` to concatenate all the TF Tensors it ouputs from the convolution. Is the problem the `tf.concat` or this layer? How should I avoid layers with eager execution?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely by removing some imports and using entire import whenever necessary solves the issue

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate # _Merge
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

The final imports only include

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I'm not sure why this resolves the issue. Need to take a look at keras API's.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).