# fit errors with custom loss function: 1) Keras Functional model construction... or 2) Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, training-data, autoencoder

**Tensorflow version:** 2.12.0

**Working environment:** Google Colab

I'm trying to train a Variational AutoEncoder (VAE) with a custom loss function, but I keep getting errors when calling the vae.fit(..) function.

1. The first error that came up was (related to the vae_Loss = tf.map_fn(....) in the **Custom loss** code):

```
TypeError: You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.operators.add_1/AddV2:0', description="created by layer 'tf.operators.add_1'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as tf.cond, tf.function, gradient tapes, or tf.map_fn. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as tf.math.add or tf.reshape. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer call and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

The error is present only when fitting a model with the following **custom loss function**, indeed  I tried to compile the vae with a std. loss='binary_crossentropy' and the fit worked with no issue.

**Custom Loss** and model compiling:

```
# Optimizer and loss function
#
# ================= #################

optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.0005)

def custom_loss(mean, log_var):
    def mse_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = K.flatten(y_true)
        y_pred = K.flatten(y_pred)

        # Reconstruction loss (as we used sigmoid activation we can use binarycrossentropy)
        r_loss = tensorflow.keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) 
        return r_loss

    def kl_loss(mean, log_var):
        # KL divergence
        kl_loss = -5e-4 * K.mean(1 + log_var - K.square(mean) - K.exp(log_var), axis=-1)


        return kl_loss

    def vae_loss(y_true, y_pred):

        r_loss = mse_loss(y_true, y_pred)
        KL_loss = kl_loss(mean, log_var)
        return   r_loss + KL_loss

    def vae_loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
        # Loop the function over a tensor
        vae_Loss = tf.map_fn(lambda x: vae_loss(x[0], x[1]), (y_true, y_pred), fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
        return K.mean(vae_Loss)

    return vae_loss_fn

# Compile VAE
vae.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=custom_loss(mean, log_var))
vae.summary()
```

Then for the fit I call:

```
vae.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs = STEPS)
```

Where I use as train_dataset a zip. dataset of an input images dataset  and a ground_truth images dataset (same structure for the validation one).

**What I've tried**: Searching online I saw that a possible way to avoid this error is to [disable the eager_execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71808327/how-to-fix-error-where-a-kerastensor-is-passed-to-a-tf-api) (disable_eager_execution() , with all the relative imports and tried all the found different variants and [additional possible compile execution commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366442/cannot-convert-a-symbolic-keras-input-output-to-a-numpy-array-typeerror-when-usi)).

2. But after tring this the error I got when calling fit is:

```
input_dataset: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

So the way to solve this would be to enable eager execution, but the 1st case error would come up again.

I'm new to both python and tensorflow, so I'm really struggling to find a feasible way to avoid these type of errors.

Maybe a possible way could be following the workaround mentioned at the end of the first error and build a custom layer to take care of the loss computation, but I'm not sure how to do it (online I've not found a way compliant with my case) and if any other possible errors might show.

The mean, log_var function inputs come from the encoder's model defined before the loss definition (z is the latent vector):

```
mean, log_var, z = encoder(input_img)
decoded = decoder(z)
vae = Model(input_img, decoded, name='vae')
```

**Other things to mention:** Before working with the dataset structures I used lists (but these take up ram, so it's feasible with relative few data). When working with lists I used basically the same custom loss function (without the *vae_loss_fn* sub-function and doing K.mean(rloss + KLloss) in the return of *vae_loss*) and fitted with:

```
vae.fit(x_train, gt_train, epochs = EPOCHS, batch_size = 64,  validation_split=0.2)
```

This worked when I disabled the eager mode as mentioned before, so I think the error in the first case it's more related to the tensor handling in the custom function so the vae_Loss = tf.map_fn(... part, but without that last vae_loss_fn function I get always the 1st same error in the end.

The imports related to tensorflow are:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, Lambda, Reshape
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
```

It would be wonderful is someone can help me with this and shed some light on these issues.